# Repository pattern: Can a repository use other repositories?

Tags: java, repository-pattern

Suppose I have a TeacherRepository that needs to make use of a CourseRepository per the code below. Teacher and Course form a many to many relationship. Teacher and Course do not form an aggregate. Would you consider this proper use of the pattern?

```
class TeacherRepository {

    @Inject(@Named("courseRepository"))
    private final CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public void addCourseToTeachers(String courseName) {

      Course course = courseRepository.findByName(courseName);

      for (Teacher teacher : readAll()) 
        teacher.addCourse(course);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it is the task of the `TeacherRepository` to deal with courses. IMHO it would be better to handle this in a separate class. It is better to keep a single responsibility for every class.

#### Update

But if you absolutely want to add this functionality to `TeacherRepository`, you can do it without any dependency to `CourseRepository`:

```
class TeacherRepository {
  public void addCourseToTeachers(Course course) {

    for (Teacher teacher : readAll()) 
      teacher.addCourse(course);
  } 
}

...
CourseRepository courseRepository = ...;
TeacherRepository teacherRepository = ...;
...
Course course = courseRepository.findByName(courseName);

if (course != null)
  teacherRepository.addCourseToTeachers(course);
```

Comment: That's what the teacher repository is for. It's to manage teachers, their course load, tenure progress, and so on. Note that addCourseToTeachers is simply calling through to a domain method on Teacher.

Comment: @Chance, apparently we have different ideas about what a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is supposed to be.

Comment: A repository is a class that encapsulates CRUD operations on the set of all objects of a single type. Only aggregate roots are exposed in repositories. Teacher has a set of Courses and modifying that set is an Update operation. If a repository can't interact with another repository to perform its work we have to create some other construct that can. That doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: @Chance, as you yourself say, the repo *encapsulates* CRUD operations. I.e. it does not expose them in its public API (because these are on a different level of abstraction). It is concerned only with persistence. You get the objects from the repo, manipulate them however you wish, then tell the repo to persist changes.

Comment: @Chance, anyway, your repository needn't interact with another repository to perform its task (if you really really want that task to be performed by the repo). Check out the code example I added.

Comment: Why is it preferable for a repo not to reference other repos at the expense of forcing a client to interact with multiple repos instead of one? I would rather provide a more concise API to the client.. That the TeacherRepository utilizes the CourseRepository is completely unknown to the client. See above changes to code.

Comment: @Chance, if you are absolutely, 100% sure that the client will never ever need to interact with the course repo directly, it may be fine to encapsulate it within the teacher repo (although even then, I would prefer a separate helper class for this, to keep one responsibility per class). However, in real life, there are always new requirements which may easily break this constraint. Just out of the top of my head: how would you create a new course when you don't yet know which teachers to assign to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar on a project and I don't see the problem in your approach (and don't necessarily believe it contradicts the views of others who have posted answers).

If I have one Aggregate Root (Teacher) which as part of it's aggregate references another aggregate (Course), I think the approach is valid for the following reasons:

1. Each repository is still responsible for CRUD operations of it's own aggregate root
2. It is still possible to create instances of the each Aggregate through the API of each repository
3. The Teacher repository still has one responsibility (To create a Teacher aggregate). It just happens that you cannot create a Teacher without the Teacher containing a reference to the taught courses.

I don't see the issue here although I may gain a better understanding as the project I'm working on unfolds!!.

JLove

Comment: One problem to think about with repositories referencing each other is a possible deadlock or endless loops.